# Which ORM tool is compatibe with Firebird 2.5?

Tags: orm, .net-4.0, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to use Firebird 2.5 SuperServer as back-end to .NET 4.0 application. Which ORM tool is compatible to work with .NET 4.0 & Firebird 2.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try out [Telerik OpenAccess ORM](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm/supported-databases.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention FREE. I am looking for open-source alternatives.

Comment: I downloaded OpenAccess but it is not recognizing Firebird Data Source.

Comment: Can you try by manually entering the Firebird connection string in the 'Connection string' textbox? That should work.

Comment: Can you provide me the connection string you entered? Maybe I can provide you with a solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

People are using [NHibernate with Firebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375132/nhibernate-with-firebird-are-these-features-enabled).

The [wiki docs](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasesSupportedByNHibernate#Firebird) list only Firebird 2.0.1, so I would download it with [NuGet](http://nuget.org/), check the supported dialects in the latest version, and test it.

Answer (score 0):

the Telerik OpenAccess ORM is free unless you want features that are not found in EF5. Basically the Telerik OpenAccess  is as good as EF otherwise why not use free EF?

I am looking for an ORM for Firebird 1.5 as the migration to 2.5 is too hard/costly and if one were to take the pain would be better to migrate to a more contemporary product, with more productive tooling such as MSSQL etc.

Answer (score 0):

Symbiotic ORM is free, but not open source.

I haven't tried it on 2.5 but it does works on the latest 3.0

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Symbiotic_Micro_ORM_Net_Standard_x64/3.0.0

There's also a helper to create your poco classes from an existing schema:
https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NN20Q6WFKGS

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework Core:  [EntityFrameworkCore.FirebirdSQL](https://github.com/ralmsdeveloper/EntityFrameworkCore.FirebirdSQL)  or [FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird/6.0.0-alpha1)